# JavaFX: Get the selected row cell's text

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I need your help.
I am developing JavaFX project that deals with table view and forms.
My Problem is I can't get the text of the selected row in the table view.
I want to get the row cell's text using the row index or the selected row one.

Here is my code:

```
myTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {

        TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = myTableView.getSelectionModel();
        ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
        TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
        int rowIndex = tablePosition.getRow(); // yields the row that the currently selected cell is in 

        // I Want to get the cell's text in the row using the row_index or the selected row one
    }
});
```

Any solution is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you only care about which row is selected, assuming you have a `TableView<SomeObject>`, you can simply use:

```
List<SomeObject> selected = selectionModel.getSelectedItems();
```

or if your table only allows single row selection:

```
SomeObject selected = selectionModel.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to get the text in each cells in the selected row.

Comment: @napstyrmaceda Once you have a reference to the relevant `SomeObject`, you can just query its fields. You might want to give a bit more background on how you populate the table initially.

Comment: Hi assylias! Thank you for that! I know how to populate table view. I also know now on how to get the data in the selected row. I just used the getter of it and convert it to string. I'll post my answer soon. Thanks!